# How to tilt a mapview?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have been able to rotate a mapview by containing a mapview in a framelayout and then overriding the dispatchdraw function of framelayout view.

but how to get the tilt effect as seen when we use the two finger swipe feature in the new google maps application?

is there a way to rotate the canvas around x or y axis?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `camera.rotateX` method, then apply it's **matrix** to your *canvas*.  Or *Y* or *Z* for that matter, but you will have to *counter rotate* any *touch events* by an *inverted matrix* (if that matters)